# How to zoom a whole QML2 scene in QQuickView?

Tags: c++, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a QML2 document which is significantly larger than the display on which it's displayed with a QQuickView.
In QML1 and QtDeclarative it was possible to use `QGraphicsView::fitInView` to scale the whole scene (including correct MouseEvent mapping, etc).

Is there something similar for QML2 I just didn't find yet?

Comment: You'd have to tinker with the modelview matrix of the scene, but last I've looked the interface for this wasn't available.

Comment: Do you think adding a QSGTransformNode as parent of a custom rootObject might help?

Comment: Can you wrap the whole document into a top-level `Item` and then zoom-move that one?

Comment: This is kind of what I did. Since I'm using a custom QQuickView I scaled the rootObject after the status changed to `QQuickView::Ready`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that somehow behaves like `QGraphicsView::fitInView(aRect, Qt::KeepAspectRatio)`.

```
void MyQuickView::fitInView(const QRectF & newRect)
{
    QSizeF newSize = newRect.size();
    qreal horizontalScale = size().width() / newSize.width();
    qreal verticalScale = size().height() / newSize.height();

    // You might want to use another origin
    rootObject()->setTransformOrigin(QQuickItem::TopLeft);

    rootObject()->setSize(newSize);
    rootObject()->setScale(qMin(horizontalScale, verticalScale));
}
```

This does mostly the job, although I haven't thoroughly tested all of my old Qt4.8 code.